# string manipulation to sort out messages from an array

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string[] array = new string[] { "12", "3$4", "5$67", "8$945", "$9484$", "$63$" };
foreach(string message in array)
{
    FindString(message);
}

string remainingString = "";
string tempString = "";
string outputString = "";
```

And this the `FindString`

```
private void FindString(string message)
{
    if(message.Contains("$"))
    {//remove char ^ process
         int pos = -1;
         pos = message.IndexOf('$');
         outputString = message.Substring(0, pos);
         remainingString = message.Substring(pos + 1);
         if(tempString != "")
         {
             outputString = tempString + outputString;
         objList.Add(outputString);
         tempString = "";
         }
         if(remainingString.Length != 0)
         {
             FindString(remainingString);
         //remainingString = "";
         }
    }
    else
    {
        tempString = tempString + message;
    }
}
```

I have build an array of messages send by another application. "$" character shows end of message.From an array i have to sort out messages which was actual message. These i have to find out "123 "45","678","945", "9484", "63" I have write a code but getting only "123","45","675","945" it skips"9484" and "63" those are inside "$$"

Comment: `fails` is very *specific* and *unambiguous* word. Could you please specify expected behavior?

Comment: insted of fails i have add actual prob

Answer (score 6):

No need for lost of lines of code. Try this:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "12", "3$4", "5$67", "8$945", "$9484$", "$63$" };
string total = string.Join(string.Empty, array);
List<string> outputString = 
                   total.Split(
                            new char[] { '$' },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome. I was just going to post about this approach. :D

Comment: Hossein your answer is great but i have to go by storing values in variable.Please suggest code like that way Sorry :(

Comment: @Means Which variable do you need?

Comment: outputString  because I have to add outputString to LIST

Comment: @Means `outputString` is always `""` because you are not changing the `pos`. And I cannot even guess what `outputString` should be.

Comment: when u run the code ouputstring gets "9484" but because of condition tempstring!="" ouputstring not adds into LIST

Comment: @Means What do you expect as the final value for the `outputString`?

Comment: "123","45","675","945" "9484" "63"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27402/discussion-between-means-and-hossein-narimani-rad)

Comment: @Means I edited my post. Check the outputString and it's "123","45","675","945" "9484" "63"